# Root and normal user can't find commands

Tags: bash, debian

I tried adding a user as root and i succesfully did it (by manually going to the /usr/sbin directory) but now i discovered a problem that I can't solve.
I tried running adduser and usermod commands but it kept showing me:

```
devusr@devsys:~$ usermod
-bash: usermod: command not found
```

So i tried adding them to the path but that didn't fix the problem:

```
devusr@devsys:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/sbin/usermod
```

I am experiencing the same issue on the user and on the root accounts.
How to fix this?

Comment: you added `/usr/sbin/usermod` , you should add `/usr/sbin`

Comment: What does it mean to add a user as root?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the command with full path:

```
$ /usr/sbin/usermod
```

if the command does not exist you have to install the package passwd (even though should be already installed)

```
$ sudo apt install passwd
```